# How to use OrderBy in jpa spring repository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to use orderBy with one properties of my entity class please any one can suggest how to use OrderBy keyword in jpa spring repository because I am not getting this keyword in default keyword list of jpa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use OrderBy with findAll in Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486583/how-to-use-orderby-with-findall-in-spring-data)

Answer (score 5):

Use can use orderBy property of Spring Data Jpa.

```
findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameDesc(String lastName)
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use OrderBy e.g.

List findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameAsc(String lastname);