# How do I use ascending in Java Spring without query native?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I want to show three rows in a table in PostgreSQL with Hibernate. If I want by id, I just use findById? How can I select with ascending without query in my repository?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-sort

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use OrderBy with findAll in Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486583/how-to-use-orderby-with-findall-in-spring-data)